# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

I am getting following error when I load bitmap on imageview in AsyncTask:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Is there any help?

Comment: My guess is that you need more physical memory, a larger allocation for your JVM, or a smaller image.

Comment: @nirav: Please look at the "Related" links (on the right of this page)

Answer (score 2):

It could be helpful to watch the memory management session of this year's google i/o: 
[Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) Here, Patrick Dubroy explains some cases which can lead to memory leaks (particularly keeping a long lived reference to the application's context via static members). He also talks about the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved the problem resampling the bitmap to lower resolution, and then using imageView.clearAnimation(); before to load the new bitmap on the imageView.
Vote me if this helps you too.
Regards.
Note: in the following sample, **data** contains the new image data for the camera image picker and **imageView** is our ImageView.

```
    Bitmap photo=null;
    imageView.clearAnimation();     
    Uri photoUri =  data.getData(); 
    InputStream imageStream = null;
    try {
    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inSampleSize=2;
    Rect outPadding= new Rect(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, outPadding, options);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
```